# Ошибка в конвертации в .png, почему пхп считает, что файл .webp некорректен?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь взять файл по ссылке в формате новомодном и сохранить себе в формате пнг. 
[Вот пример файла, который беру по ссылке.](http://sdev.ml/1.webp)

Вот код, который с другими файлами работает корректно, а с данным файлом или другими фото с плеймаректа гугловского - выдает ошибку.

```
// Load the WebP file
$im = imagecreatefromwebp('http://sdev.ml/1.webp');

// Convert it to a jpeg file with 100% quality
imagejpeg($im, 'example.jpeg', 100);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Но получаю следующие ошибки:

```
 Warning: imagecreatefromwebp(): WebP decode: fail to decode input data in W:\domains\gpget.ru\index.php on line 107

 Warning: imagecreatefromwebp(): 'http://sdev.ml/1.webp' is not a valid WEBP file in W:\domains\gpget.ru\index.php on line 107

 Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in W:\domains\gpget.ru\index.php on line 110

 Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in W:\domains\gpget.ru\index.php on line 111
```

Comment: Проверьте что установлена последняя версия libwebp (0.5) и последняя версия libgd(2.2.2).

Answer (score 2):

Да правильно подмечено в комментариях по поводу версии libwebp , libgd,
надо проверить и их версионность и совместимость с вашей PHP.

Эта ошибка о том что файл не валидный

Вообще-то доверять расширению файла смотря в url нельзя.

Картинки может оказаться не webp a png

Читай mime файла, а потом уже через switch соответвующий imagecreatefrom...()

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
echo $finfo->buffer('http://sdev.ml/1.webp');
```

В вашем случае mime = text/plain; charset=us-ascii

А должен был быть по моему application/webp

Comment: спасибо за наводку, скоро поставлю галочку вашем ответу! Однако, может в знаете как всё-таки конвертировать такие файлы? Я уже в отчаянии

Comment: Дело в том что этого файла даже не существут var_dump(file_exists('http://sdev.ml/1.webp'));
Я посмотрел в заголовки но данный момент миме типе application/xhtml+xml.
А несколько минут назад был другим.

Comment: странно дело. Я посмотрю завтра, залью пару тестовых файлов и проверю еще раз. Вы говорите файла ка бы нет, но по ссылке есть же вроде? полноценная картинка....

Comment: Смотри html to image php script http://buffernow.com/html-to-image-php-script/,
но это все хакнутые варианты ,
тут он конвертирует html в pdf а потом pdf   в image.

Comment: Там по моему редирект 304 стоит  в заголовках . Вот очередное что я получил при попытке 
Impossible to load the image http://sdev.ml/1.webp.

единственное что можно сделать это найти какой нибудь php lib html to image и передать ему так 
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://sdev.ml/1.webp">

Comment: Да и кстати сайт не рабочий  http://sdev.ml/, он в оффлайн режиме,
оттуда и заголовок redirect 304